# Combustion of Sodium (Na) Metal in presence of Excess Air

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, combustion, alkali-metals

There was a question which I was recently solving regarding the products formed after combustion of **Sodium Metal** in presence of **Excess Air**.

The given answers were Na2O2 (sodium peroxide) and Na2O (sodium oxide).

But on the contrary, a textbook I refer to gave the products to the reaction as Na2O2 and NaO2 (superoxide)

[image: Ncert grade 11 (s-block elements)]

I was wondering if someone could clarify what the **correct reaction** and **final products** would be to the reaction ?

**Reference:**

1. [Ncert textbook (grade 11) S-Block elements](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kech203.pdf)

Comment: @NilayGhosh although the answer explains how Na2O2 is formed, my primary doubt is whether NaO2 or Na2O is formed in the reaction along with Na2O2.

Comment: @Hydro_7, All three can be formed as a mixture. The exact proportion will depend on the exact conditions. So you can follow your textbook.